setting cookie using javascript in new Chrome did not work
document.cookie='clientDeviceId=f586e1cb-8af3-478c-ae0d-7f01fea6e4be;expires=Sat, 11 Aug 2029 02:23:52 GMT;path=/'

it did not show up in Application/Cookies. It worked before (older Chrome version).
Chrome version: 127.0.6533.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
